# Visual Studio 2015 keeps crashing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

No idea why but after I added a regular cshtml view visual stdio 2015 keeps on crashing whenever I open the file to edit it.
I saw some answers here on stackoverflow.com but non worked I even repaired the installation and no luck.
When i checked the error log it gave me no info, just an error with a blank description.
Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the file and the controller was excluded from the project, after I included it in the project the problem was solved.